# What is equivalents per mole?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

> Which has maximum number of equivalents per mole of the oxidant?
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{MnO4- + H2O2 &-> Mn^2+ + O2}\tag{i}\\
> \ce{Cr2O7^2- + Fe^2+ &-> 2 Cr^3+ + Fe^3+}\tag{ii}
> \end{align}
> $$

The answer is the second option. I wanna know why

If there's another term different from equivalent mass like equivalents, then I tried doing it using the formula = No.of moles of oxidant x n factor (no of electrons gained)

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: The question does not make sense to me---what should 'equivalents' mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can be understood as:
Which one of the following oxidants has a greater n-factor as there's only 1 mole each of permanganate ion and dichromate ion.

The n-factor of permanganate ion is (7-2)=5

while

The n-factor of dichromate ion is (6*2-3*2)=6

So, the answer is the 2nd reaction.

Comment: Oh now I understand, So in general n factor is the initial oxidation state * no.of atoms - final oxidation*no.of atoms ?

Comment: Is the equivalent mentioned here the same as equivalent weight

Comment: n-factor is basically the number of moles of electrons being exchanged in the reaction. And equivalent weight is the weight of the species required for the exchange of one mole of electrons.